# Can't access JSON data returned from PUT ajax method

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, put

I'm trying to get one of the values from the JSON data returned by a PUT method but I keep getting 'undefined'. Does anyone knows why?

```
$( "#forminventory" ).submit(function( event ) {
        var item = {
            name: $("#name").val(),
            category: $("#category").val(),
            amount: $("#amount").val(),
            date: $("#date").val(),
            location: $("#location").val()
        };

        item = JSON.stringify(item);

        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost:8080/new',
            type: 'PUT',
            data: item,
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            accept: 'Application/json',
            success: function(result) {

                $(".sortable").append( "<tr><td>" + $("#name").val() + "</td><td>" + $("#category").val() + "</td><td>" + $("#amount").val() + "</td><td>" + $("#date").val() + "</td><td>" + $("#location").val() + "</td><td><button id=\"edit-btn-" + result.id + "\" type=\"button\">Edit</button><button id=\"delete-btn-" + result.id + "\" type=\"button\">Delete</button></td></tr>");

                //clear fields
                $( "#name, #category, #amount, #date, #location" ).val("");
            }
    });


    event.preventDefault();  //prevent default action from happening 
});
```

The result.id is undefined. I gave no idea why. Any thoughts?

Comment: And the script that is receiving the request.

Comment: What does `console.log(result)` say?

Comment: Have you watched the request / response in the browser's console?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed by adding `result = JSON.parse(result);` and then calling `result[0].id`

Comment: `result` should already be an object already because you've specified `dataType: 'json'`. Attempting to call `JSON.parse` on an object will cause an error (because the `toString` representation of an object, `[object Object]`, is not a valid JSON string). The fact that you are accessing `result[0].id` here and `result.id` in the question code suggests you may have simply been accessing the wrong property in the question code (i.e., accessing `id` instead of `0`).